# ConsoleBuilder - Adding Filtering (part of Search) Features

Tags: sccm

I find Microsoft's documentation for ConsoleBuilder to be poor. I've managed to create a custom device view, which almost does everything I want.

But, the search function is slow and expensive on server resources. I'm currently just pulling a static list that can be re-ordered via column headers. Does anyone know how to get the ['criteria' functionality](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-clWEkHwg4OE/UsCrR6BkwUI/AAAAAAAABqM/BjW6M0mW46s/s1600/AddSearchCriteria.JPG) enabled (like Powershell's [Out-GridView](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/gridview-drivereport2.png)) without using search to process the database directly?

I can't see any tabs with this set-up, so it may not be possible anyway.

Any ideas on this (or even some decent documentation in general!) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the general tab for your particular view form in Console Builder, you will find a field called Search Folder ID. Giving this a value enables the search function.

The search function includes a criteria section, which allows you to search via all relevant fields for the displayed query datasets. The criteria search is faster than the universal searchbar function. (Details on optimising the universal search function are currently unknown to me.)

[image: This is a link to a picture which shows the field in the form.]

More information can be found here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/matt_hinsons_manageability_blog/2013/08/21/using-configmgr-2012-console-builder-create-custom-console-nodes/

Check Step 6, more specifically